Facing Issue in DFA Report as "Graph Engine reached the path expansion upper limit (1600)."
I’m encountering an issue when generating a Dynamic Flow Analysis (DFA) report in Salesforce. The process preemptively stops with an error message indicating that the path expansion upper limit (1600) has been reached to prevent an OutOfMemory error. However, this issue does not occur when I change the method visibility from global to public.
Changing the method visibility from global to public, which avoids the error but is not a feasible solution in my case.

Based on your tags, is this an AppExchange app?
